# Two containers overlap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I created a new container after an existing container(background image set). The newly added container gets overlapped with the old one. I have increased the padding-top and it works well. But it is necessary to write for all the container classes we use?See image (https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bwyjk1QbhhGGXzRuMm4tcDhJeWc/edit)..

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-5 col-lg-offset-1   col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-1">
        <img src="images/logos-1.png" class="img-responsive"/>
      </div>    

      <div class="col-lg-5 col-lg-offset-1   col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-1">
        <img src="images/logos-2.png" class="img-responsive"/>
      </div>    
</div> <!--row-->
</div>

<!--SECOND CONTAINER-->

<div class="container has-bg1">

    <div class="row" >
        <div class="col-lg-4  col-xs-4">
            <img src="images/blueprint_logo1.png" class="img-responsive"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4  col-xs-4" >
            <img src="images/blueprint_logo2.png" class="img-responsive"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4  col-xs-4" >
            <img src="images/blueprint_logo3.png" class="img-responsive"/>
        </div>  
   </div><!--row-->
```

**CSS:**
      .container.has-bg {
      background-image:url(images/book_bg.png);
      background-size: cover;
      }
      .container.has-bg1 {
      background-image: url(images/blueprint.png);
      background-size: cover;
      }

Comment: Can you post your HTML or create a [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com)?

Comment: @Skelly I edited the question. Can you pls check it on.

Answer (score 1):

Have you used a .row inside the container?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It is also not necessary to replace the .container every time, You can just place everything inside one container

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            First row content
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            Second row content
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```